# Attempting to import a variable from parent module breaks other imports

Tags: python

I know this question is probably asked over and over again, and I've come a long way in understanding how `import` works with Python. I did what I could to try to understand it as much as possible before asking but I'm completely lost with what I feel like is a very simple `import` to perform.

I need access to the `app` variable in a child module (user.py) to specifically use `app.config`. My structure is as follows:

```
src
 | - __init__.py
 | - app.py
 | - models
   | - __init__.py
   | - user.py
```

my `app.py` file looks something like:

```
from flask import Flask, make_response, abort, jsonify, g
from flask_restful import Api
from flask_login import LoginManager, current_user

from models import db
from apis.v1.tasks import TaskAPI, TaskListAPI
from apis.v1.users import UserAPI, UserListAPI
from apis.v1 import auth

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = "mysql+pymysql://root:root@localhost/database"
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = "loremIpsumDolorSitAmet"

# More code n stuff
```

I'd like to get my hands on `app` so I can reference `app.config['SECRET_KEY']` in my `models/user.py` module.

So I've tried what seems like *everything* (from `models/user.py`).

```
from src import app
from src.app import app
from .. import app
```

Most of the time I get an error similar to `ImportError: No module named src.app`, but sometimes I'll get an error like `ImportError: cannot import name User` that frankly confuses me because it's almost like the import is successful but causes some sort of loop?

I was really hoping that [this guide to imports](https://chrisyeh96.github.io/2017/08/08/definitive-guide-python-imports.html) would give me the info I need, and while it's helped me a lot with child/sibling imports as well as understanding modules/packages/etc..., it just isn't helping me out with this latest issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: OK, so what I did to fix this is I created a separate `config/` package so now the folder structure is,

```
src
 | - __init__.py
 | - app.py
 | - config
   | - __init__.py
 | - models
   | - __init__.py
   | - user.py
```

And in `app.py` I'm accessing it via `app.config.from_object('config')` and in my `user.py` I'm calling `from config import SECRET_KEY`.

Comment: What is the value of `PYTHONPATH`? That is, from which point should the Python interpreter look at your module hierachy?

Comment: Naming your package `src` is a rather bad idea. Packages share a common namespace and you are probably not the first one to use that name.

Comment: @9000 Not entirely sure if this is the correct answer, but I run everything via `./app.py`.

Comment: Can you please post the imports done in your `app.py`?

Comment: @9000 added the requested imports!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried only `import app`?

It seems you should be working with blueprints and an [application factory](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/appfactories/) pattern and [blueprints](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/blueprints/). Is that the case?

Comment: `import app` gives me the `ImportError: cannot import name User` error. I've started seeing more and more info about blueprints when I tried troubleshooting this issue - I'll look into the pattern. Hopefully it both helps me out and clears things up for the future.

Comment: Definitely do. Your folder and file structure already points to app factory as the solution to all your problems. [Miguel Grinberg's Mega Tutorial](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world) was really helpful for me to grasp the concept. Also, [Flask Foundation](https://github.com/JackStouffer/Flask-Foundation) is a good starting point for your Flask projects, and uses the app factory pattern as well.

Comment: Oh thanks so much for those recommendations! Super appreciated!